# Efficient value retrieval stored in a generic typed member without having to use ChangeType or Convert.ToType

Tags: c#, generics

Consider a class

```
public class Fraction<T> 
{
      public T Numerator{get; set;}
      public T Denominator{get; set;}

      public double GetValue() {
           if(T is int) --do something --
           if(T is long) --do something --
      }
}
```

T is either int or long. The GetValue method returns a double precision value. I want to return the value in an efficient manner without having to use ChangeType or Convert.ToInt32 or Convert.ToInt64

Comment: Exactly all of them are not super efficient, and one of them could be the most efficient. TryParse needs an extra .ToString(), Convert.To uses reflection internally, ChangeType uses reflection too internally. If I were to repeat GetValue over a million objects then all three above have different efficiencies. There could be a more efficient way, or any of the above could be marked as the most efficient by experts here.

Answer (score 3):

You can restrict your generic type to be `IConvertible` (which both long and int implement), then do this:

```
public class Fraction<T> where T : struct, IConvertible {
    public T Numerator { get; set; }
    public T Denominator { get; set; }

    public double GetValue() {
        return Numerator.ToDouble(null) / Denominator.ToDouble(null);
        // or return Numerator.ToInt64(null) / (double) Denominator.ToInt64(null); etc
    }
}
```

Then no reflection or string conversion is used (`ToDouble` will just do `(double) this` for both int and long), and no need to use type-checking.

Answer (score 0):

int can be implicitly converted to long, so you can probably do something like this:

```
public long GetValue() {
     if(T is int || T is long) 
         return Value;
    throw new Exception("Only int and long types are supported");
}
```

However, I don't really see the point in such a class anyway.

Comment: I have modified the question, instead of a long, say I was calculating fraction value, then I must calculate double value, what could be the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Same same. int and long can both be implicitly converted to double.

Comment: Would that be the most efficient too?